# how to configure gearman_proxy to handle inbound flows between workers and gearmand?

Tags: proxy, gearman

We configured a centralized Nagios / Mod_Gearman with multiple Gearman worker to monitor our servers. I need to monitor remote servers deploying gearman workers on the remote site. But, for security reasons, I would like to reverse the direction of the initial connection between these workers and the neb module (inconming flows from workers to our network are forbidden). The Gearman proxy seems to be the solution since it just puts jobs from the "central" gearmand into another gearmand.

I would like to know if it's possible to configure the gearman proxy to send informations to a remote gearmand and get check results from it without having to open inbound flows ?

Unfortunately, the documentation does not give use cases about that. Do you know were I could find more documentation about gearman proxy configurations ?